# MVC redirect from view to controller with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to redirect to controller action from view.
My code in View looks like this.

```
<table id="tableid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="Sno">S No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    @foreach (var sd in Model.Details)
    {

      <tr id="trid">
        <td>@sd .Id</td>
        <td>@sd .Name</td>
        <td>@sd .Status</td>
        <td>

          <a id="actionId"   onclick="Clickfn()"  >
          </a>
          <script>
            function Clickfn() {
              window.location.href = '@Url.Action("UpdateCamp", "CampDashboard", new {id =@sd .Id })'
            }
          </script>

          </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Code returns last Id of @sd .Id while clicking on  tag..how to get that particular cell value (cell in which  tag is present.)

Comment: Why do it with javascript? You can just use `@foreach (var sd in Model.Details) { @Html.ActionLink(sd.Name, "UpdateCamp", "CampDashboard", new {ID = sd.ID }) }`

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the value to the `a` element using a `data` attribute which you can then use in the `click` handler:

```
@foreach (var sd in Model.Details)
{
    <tr id="trid">
        <td>@sd .Id</td>
        <td>@sd .Name</td>
        <td>@sd .Status</td>
        <td>
            <a id="actionId" data-id="@sd.Id" href="#"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

```js
$('#tableid a').click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("UpdateCamp", "CampDashboard")?id=' + $(this).data('id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**Html.ActionLink**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx), it *returns an anchor element (a element) that contains the virtual path of the specified action*.

```
<td>
  @Html.ActionLink(sd.Name, "UpdateCamp", "CampDashboard", new {id = @sd.Id})
</td>
```

OR

You can't pass JavaScript variable to `Url.Action`. futher `Url.Action` function will render a string. You should replace string.

You should pass `@sd.Id` as paramter to `Clickfn()`

Use

```
@foreach (var sd in Model.Details)
 {
    <td>
    <tr>
    <a id="actionId" onclick="Clickfn(@sd.Id)"></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
 }
<script>
    function Clickfn(id) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateCamp", "CampDashboard", new {id = -1})'; //Generate URL string using razor
        window.location.href = url.replace('-1', id); //replace ID value
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks ..var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateCamp", "CampDashboard", new {id = -1})'; //Generate URL string using razor
        window.location.href = url.replace('-1', id); is working for me

Comment: @shalinigarg, I would recommed you to use `Html.ActionLink`

Comment: if i have to pass name and status also with Id in href.then how i can pass it.

Comment: @shalinigarg, use `@Html.ActionLink(sd.Name, "UpdateCamp", "CampDashboard", new {ID = sd.ID, Name =sd.Name, Status=sd.Status }`

Answer (score 1):

Correct anchor tag as :-

```
<a id="actionId" onclick="Clickfn(@sd.Id)" >
```

and change `Clickfn` as :

```
 <script>
    function Clickfn(Id) {
     window.location.href ="/CampDashboard/UpdateCamp?id" + Id;
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: This will not work as you are passing a static value to the URL in the `Clickfn` fucntion.

Comment: @DavidG...it's not a static value its inside foreach just look at the question carefully..

Comment: That's better, though I was hoping you'd take on the bet! No idea how we'd exchange the points though, maybe I should do a feature request on meta haha

Comment: @downvoter plz explain what is wrong with this answer??